# What is more performant , tiling a small CCSprite or 1 complete fullscreen background?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a background that consist of white and red squares. that are 10 by 10 pixels in dimensions.

I have two options and I don't know which one is best.

1.
I could save a png file of 960x480px filled with red/white squares in my 2048x2048 texture map and then set the background as one complete image.

OR
2. I could save a png file of 10x10px in my 2048x2048 texture map. and then in code tile this across the whole screen.

What is more performant?

Comment: that's very easy to test ... just do it.

Comment: tiles with batch node is more performant. Have you looked into Tiled map editor and .tmx files? It's a very easy way to set up what you are describing in cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

I've never developed for iPhone, but I can hypothesize and offer a few thoughts:

1. This feels like it's probably premature performance optimization.
2. I don't image this will make much difference between the two.
3. Using a tiling method is more future proof, and will work on more screen sizes (like tablets) without extra work.

All that said, on the performance side, you're basically doing this:

1. Grabbing your image from memory.
2. Displaying it on the screen.

In the tiling case, you have to tile it across the screen vertically and horizontally, which will take some processing. In the non-tiling case, you'll have to pull a bigger image out of memory, which will take longer. Which of these two time-takers takes longer, I do not know. You may have to profile it.

Answer (score 0):

put one copy of your red and white sprites in a single .pvr.ccz file (prepare with a tool like TexturePacker) ... then create a CCSpriteBatchNode with the texture. Finally, replicate the red and white squares as CCSprites that you will add to the batch node. Add the batch node to your scene. Voila, save on bundle size, and core memory, with hardly any performance impact because you used a batch node (all sprites are drawn in a single GL call).